# How to create i18n from OData services in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I want to get rid of i18n files in `SAPUI5` applications. I developed an OData service that provides all the translations and removed `i18n` model from `manifest.json`. Also I create `i18n` model based on my OData service in `Component.js`.But I don't know why the elements does not bind to data of my i18n model.

Here is my code for creating Odata model:

```
oDataModel.read("/TranslationConfigSet", {
            async: false,
            filters: aFilter,
            success: function(oData, response) {
                var aI18n = {};
                var results = oData.results;
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    aI18n[results[i]["ZStringKey"]] = results[i]["ZTranslation"];
                }
                var oI18nModel = new JSONModel(aI18n);
                _this.setModel(oI18nModel, "i18n");
            },
            error: function(oError) {

            }
        });
```

This code is placed inside of my Component.js file and inside of the xml view files I have some codes like this:

```
text="{i18n>TESTSTRING}"
```

While TESTSTRING exists in my data and my array.

Comment: how did you define "_this" in that case? the idea is great by the way... let the community know if you solve this. great post!

Comment: I hope to be able to solve it. `var _this=this;` outside of the callback function.

Comment: I don't get it, why this should be an good idea? Adding OData related overhead to load translations, storing translations in a JSONModel and having to adopt to a different binding syntax, losing the functionality of the ResourceModel... where is the advantage?

Comment: I don't get it either. @zyrex: Why is it a great idea? Martin: Would you mind to share the reason behind your decision? Why would you want to get translations from the server (and paying an extra **synchronous** round trip) instead of storing them on the client side? I'm lacking experience in SAP NW/GW stuff, so I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @boghyon First it is not related to SAP NW. It is related to SAPUI5. Second manipulation of data in DB is easier than some files.

Comment: The ResourceModel does not care where your translations are stored, file or database. It just loads translations from a standardized URL. So it is possible to stick with the standard manifest approach and deliver the translation from a backend service.

Comment: @matbtt Can you support your comment inside of a answer with some codes?

Comment: I try to understand the business case where translations from backend should be favored over the standard UI5 approach. After all, i18n is one of the powerful key features in UI5. Getting rid of this in order to achieve the same thing with several sync XHRs is a huge question mark for me. Are texts with placeholders in `*.properties`-files not flexible enough? I didn't get your argument "manipulation of data in DB is easier". What data? What does data have to do with translations?

Comment: @boghyon i18n files are fine when you want just deliver one or two application. When you want to deliver hundreds of application for a huge project modifications of those files is difficult. While a table you can provide a better feel for you application. (the feel part of "look and feel"). You can store all texts in a table and reuse the sentences in different applications.

Comment: @matbtt, Martin: Thank you for the explanations. I just found the documentation on how to load i18n.properties from the backend: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/be/1bde1361954f719dcc38388b29a75a/content.htm. It's not comprehensive, but it shows that creating a custom JSONModel for i18n might not be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have missed the slash(/) in the binding syntax. The [binding syntax](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/d5/2e364907f94a3caeb4f5e5ad0cf302/content.htm) for a JSON model is different from the Resource bundle syntax. So your binding should be

```
text="{i18n>/TESTSTRING}"
```

Comment: The only problem is that it renders the view before receiving data from backend. How can I load this files before rendering or postpone the rendering?

Comment: since you are loading it from an odata service, it will dependent on the OData latency. You could maybe have a busy indicator set which can be hidden once the model.read completes

Comment: Yes that is an option but I will ask this question to see is there any other possibilities?

Comment: Delaying the rendering may not be a good idea visually. Opening a new thread for this is a good idea. The community out there may have some good ideas